# Search and replace html element from string

Tags: php, regex

How do I remove all form elements and their contents using php. What pattern should I insert in preg_replace;

HTML string:

```
<p>Hey I am a boy</p>
<form id='id1' class='class1'>Content</form>
<p>Hey I am a girl</p>
<form id='id1' class='class1'>content</form>
```

Preg_replace should return string:

```
<p>I am a boy</p>
<p>Hey I am a girl</p>
```

i want all form elements stripped out of return string

Comment: strip tag solve ur problem http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: is strip_tags will remove the tag contents also?

Comment: strip tag wasnt sufficient as all html tags apart from <form> where needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with an empty string.

```
(?s)(^|\n)?<form\b.*?<\/form>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nB2dV5/3)

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching
                         \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                         matching normally) (matching whitespace
                         and # normally)
(                        group and capture to \1 (optional):
  ^                        the beginning of the string
 |                        OR
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
)?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                         quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                         repetition of the captured pattern will be
                         stored in \1)
<form                    '<form'
\b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         something that is not a word char
.*?                      any character (0 or more times)
<                        '<'
\/                       '/'
form>                    'form>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form[^>]*>((?!<\/form>).)*<\/form>
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/17

Comment: works but replaces the form element with a page break which wasnt ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
preg_replace('#<form*>*</form>#isU','',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tag to remove all tags but pass the `<p>` as a second parameter to return only that.

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<p>');
```

If that doesn't work, use:

```
echo preg_replace('/<form[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/form[^>]*>/', '', '$text);
```

Comment: It doesn't remove contents of tags other than `<p>`. `strip_tags` only strips tags and don't remove content.